# Cascading for Lookup column with multiple selections

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have implemented cascading for list lookup columns using JQuery, where lookup columns were of single selection type only.

But now I have a situation where I have to Implement cascading for lookup columns which can take multiple selections.

Code for single selection cascading of lookup columns:-

```
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Display Name of Master List",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Parent Column Internal Name from Master List",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Child Column Internal Name from Master List",
        parentColumn: "Parent Column Display Name from List/Library",
        childColumn: "Child Column Display Name from List/Library"
    });
```

Comment: I have implemented this, for multiple values also the same code works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

Change the settings to `'Allow Multiple value Select`' in the lookup column.

Then use the below code in the script

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Display Name of Master List",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Parent Column Internal Name from Master List",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Child Column Internal Name from Master List",
        parentColumn: "Parent Column Display Name from List/Library",
        childColumn: "Child Column Display Name from List/Library"
    });
```

For child Column call the column with the 'Title' of lookup field instead of 'ID'